Deploying private GitHub repository changes to Bluehost shared server
I've attempted to use a webhook to automatically pull changes to a Bluehost server from my private repository (as discussed here) but am unable to do so as I would require sudo privileges which I do not have on a shared server.
Is there any other way to accomplish this without having sudo privileges?

You could use a Personal Access Token to authenticate during your pull request, instead of SSH keys.
Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens, create a new token, with the appropriate permissions for your use case, then perform your pull request with the token in the Authorization header. (see this answer on a related question).
Edit: You can also just enter the token in the git login password field when prompted, instead of adding it in the request headers.
Edit 2: I would also think about token storage. This of course, is an issue, the size of which is directly analogous to your project's security criticality, which, judging by the choice of a shared system, shouldn't be too high.
